# Method Swizzling to keep a cleaner Class implementation

Tags: ios, method-swizzling

I'm in the situation where one of the viewControllers of my app is getting pretty big, specially since I've added a "Tutorial state" which adds a different implementation for many methods of this class that I control by checking

```
_tutorialEnabled?
```

So, my question is if this is a good use case for method swizzling, I could have this different implementations of these methods in a separate category and swizzle them when required, it might help me reduce the amount of code of the default implementation. Any comments or suggestions of other techniques are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not what method swizzling was designed for.

Personally I would create a subclass of the view controller that manages tutorial related stuff. Then, depending on whether or not the tutorial is enabled, you instantiate either the tutorial controller or its superclass. This is what polymorphism was designed for: to avoid endless `if`/`else`/`switch`es.

Comment: Thanks for answering Christian, you guys are right, subclassing should do the work.  Can you please give me some more suitable use cases for method Swizzling?

Comment: Method swizzling is generally used if you want to extend behavior of classes where you don't control their instantiation. You can't say "hey I want this to be my class so I get my behavior". Categories would do the job - but then again you can't call super in categories. This is where swizzling kicks in. It lets you call super.

Comment: @Andrespch Swizzling is a technique of last resort. When you need to get into another class' method, but you can't wrap the method call, can't subclass and don't have access to the class' source. Only then, should you start thinking of swizzling.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you subclass? Create a tutorial subclass of your view controller with all the needed logic. Present the tutorial in the real view controller's `-viewDidAppear:` using a full screen modal without animation. When the tutorial is over dismiss the model without animation.

```
if _tutorialEnabled != nil && _tutorialEnabled {
    tutorialViewController = …
    tutorialViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
    presentViewController(tutorialViewController, animated: NO) {}
}
```

Comment: Well you are right, overriding those methods should be enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, I wouldn't use method swizzling for this. It's a bit like using a sledgehammer to knock in a thumbtack.

Unlike others I also would not subclass a view controller, maintaining understandable flow around view lifecycle events is really important when you want to add other functionality later.

Instead I would use the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for this. In your init you could do something like this:

```
if (tutorialEnabled) {
    self.behaviour = [TutorialBehaviour new];
} else {
    self.behaviour = [NormalBehaviour new];
}
```

Then when you need to do something that changes you just call a method on your behaviour eg.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [self.behaviour load]
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tristan, I believe this wouldn't work for me since in in these methods I want to have different implementations for I need to reference properties of my ViewController. 
Am I right to think it wouldn't work for my case scenario?

Comment: @Andrespch You could make it work by exposing those properties and passing a weak reference of yourself to the strategy. But then again, it really is only an ugly subclass in a separate file.

Comment: Possibly not, it depends on your specific situation, often your behaviour methods could take one or 2 arguments and return something and this would be enough, other times you need to do something completely different like MVVM to deal with the extra complexity. http://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/mvvm/